# How can I wait for a message to be consumed on MassTransit Test Harness?

Tags: c#, .net-core, integration-testing, masstransit

I'm performing integrations tests on my dotnet runtime and I am using MassTransit TestHarness to simulate a message broker. Everything works great, but I can't find an easy way to lock the tests main thread to wait for the messages to be consumed. Currently I'm using a loop with delay tasks, (which works), but was hoping for a more synchronous approach. Any suggestions?

This is the integration test app runtime setup:

[image: integration test setup]

I tried the following solution which works, but I wasn't able to have it working with the commented statement.

[image: message consumption lock]

Comment: Add your entire test to the question, or there isn't enough information to know. If your consumer takes a long time to produce or consume the message you can use `SetTestTimeouts` to increase the inactivity timeout.

Comment: It's a .NET core Web API application integration test using the Microsoft application factory to execute the application. Have updated the post with more info. Meanwhile, your suggestions to use `SetTestTimeouts` worked, thank you

Comment: There is a [sample](https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-WebApplicationFactory) to integrate with WebApplicationFactory that might help you.